# Find Values using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string value as shown below. How do I return all values contained in quotes.
Below the answer is 70116280,05/06/2014 16:31:38,etc......essentially the answer is everything contained in quotes fired into a list.

**String Value**

```
<!-- Capacitor Stack Signoff Record -->
<stack_signoff_result lead_traveler="70116280" date="05/06/2014 16:31:38" 
    employee_id="testuser" total_energy="77.266345" status="true" 
    operation_mode="Manual" result_detail="NA">
  <signoff_data>
    <adhesive part_number="1234" kanban_number="5678"/>
  </signoff_data>
  <capacitor_set>
    <top_capacitor traveler="45911012" energy="26.000567" capacitance="0.000287553595"/>
    <middle_capacitor traveler="45817588" energy="25.576334" capacitance="0.00028426705"/>
    <bottom_capacitor traveler="45911141" energy="25.689444" capacitance="0.000284239714"/>
  </capacitor_set>
</stack_signoff_result>
```

Comment: Q: Is this a good example?  I don't see any values: I'd expect something like `-date 6/8/2014`, instead of just "-date".  In any case, look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397915.aspx.  Post back with any specific questions (and code you've tried).

Comment: @FoggyDay check question again. Its hard to write a question on a tablet....

Comment: Use [System.Xml.Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.aspx).

Comment: @user1438082: You never even remotely implied you were using XML in your original post!  Thank you for the update.  If "parsing XML in .Net/LINQ" is the question, then System.XML.Linq and System.Xml.XPath is the answer! Here is a good article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387057.aspx.    Be sure to "Accept" Stan's answer below!

Comment: @FoggyDay Apologies, I had the XML included in the question but because the formatting was initially incorrect, it did not show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use XPath queires:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

...

XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(stringValue);

var xpath = @"//stack_signoff_result[@lead_traveler='70116280']";
var result = from item in document.XPathSelectElements(xpath)
    select item;

foreach (var item in result)
{
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE:** To get all quoted attributes values you can use the LINQ oneliner below (I have formatted it for readability, but you can flatten the code to the single line).

```
var result = string.Join(
    ",",
    XElement
        // Parse xml or can reuse element found in code above
        .Parse(string value)
        // Search in element and all its descendants
        .DescendantsAndSelf()
        // Select all atributtes (quoted values)
        .SelectMany(item => item.Attributes())
        // Select attribute value
        .Select(item => item.Value)
);
```

This solution is not so fast as string manipulations, but more stable. For example, if in the code of Enigmativity will be a quotes inside text node, you'll get wrong results.

Also its more easy to mix with search task you've written in the first version:

```
var result = XDocument
    .Parse(stringValue)
    .XPathSelectElements(@"//stack_signoff_result[@lead_traveler='70116280']")
    .Select(item =>
        string.Join(
            ",",
            item.DescendantsAndSelf()
            .SelectMany(element => element.Attributes())
            .Select(element => element.Value)
        )
    )
;
```

Comment: The must be a one liner that returns all values contained in quotes to a list.

Comment: Code above updated. You can mix it with previous code into one liner, that will both find required XML elements (as in the first version of the question) and get all attributes formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var result = String.Join("", text.Split('"').Where((x, n) => n % 2 == 1));
```

I got this:

```
7011628005/06/2014 16:31:38testuser77.266345trueManualNA123456784591101226.0005670.0002875535954581758825.5763340.000284267054591114125.6894440.000284239714
```